# How can I execute a sequence of statements interactively?

Tags: debugging, interactive

I'm fairly new to Mathematica.  Suppose I have the following function:

```
f[x_Integer] := Module[{y, z, r},
    y = 5;
    z = 10;
    r = x + y + z;
    r
];
```

and I would like to halt the execution after each of the statements `y = 5`, `z = 10` and `r = x + y + z`, and resume only after I press a key.  (In other words, I'm looking for something like `Console.ReadLine()` in `C#` or `getline()` in `C++`.)  Is there an easy way to do this in Mathematica?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I think `Input[]` does the trick.  Is the the idiomatic way of implementing the desired outcome?

Comment: Maybe by using built-in debugger? - [**see here**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8363520/1146809)

Comment: I will certainly look into that.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @Shredderroy A natural way is to keep open an extra notebook in which to run the code pieces you want to check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fairly crude way to do this is to use e.g. `DialogInput` or friends, but then you have to intersperse your code with a lot of unnecessary lines:

```
f[x_Integer] := Module[{y, z, r}, y = 5;
   DialogInput["Proceed with z = 10;\n{y,z,r} = " <> ToString@{y, z, r}];
   z = 10;
   DialogInput["Proceed with r = x + y + z;\n{y,z,r} = " <> ToString@{y, z, r}];
   r = x + y + z;
   DialogInput["Proceed with r\n{y,z,r} = " <> ToString@{y, z, r}];
   r];

f[1]
```

Comment: this is nice idea..!

Comment: Thank you very much.  I will use this for now, until I am ready to spring for `Workbench`.